# Inside PCs Can't Reach My DMZ for the WWW and email Servers

Tags: firewall

Just before I post I would like to thank – Shane Madden... for pushing me forward to dig dipper and find a solution.

Today I got my ASA 5520 version7 up running on my network.

My question is: everything is working fine but the big issue is this. PCs from the Inside Zone can't reach my DMZ servers (the www and the email servers) which means that internal PCs can't browse www and can't even ping the servers from the internal IP address such as 172.16.16.80 for the www and the 172.16.16.25 for the mail server.

Please can someone help me to figure out what is really wrong with my below `sh run`, and probably if I got some misconfiguration confusion as well.

```
ASA Version 7.0(8)
!
hostname ASA2
domain-name xxxxxx
enable password xxxxxx
passwd 
names
dns-guard
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 description "Link-To-GW-Router"
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 41.223.156.109 255.255.255.248
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 description Link To Local Lan
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.1.4.1 255.255.252.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 description "Link-To-DMZ"
 nameif dmz
 security-level 50
 ip address 172.16.16.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface Management0/0
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
ftp mode passive
access-list INSIDE extended permit ip 10.1.4.0 255.255.252.0 any
access-list OUT-TO-DMZ extended permit tcp any host 41.223.156.107 eq smtp
access-list OUT-TO-DMZ extended permit tcp any host 41.223.156.106 eq www
access-list OUT-TO-DMZ extended permit icmp any any log
access-list OUT-TO-DMZ extended deny ip any any
access-list inside extended permit tcp any any eq pop3
access-list inside extended permit tcp any any eq smtp
access-list inside extended permit tcp any any eq ssh
access-list inside extended permit tcp any any eq telnet
access-list inside extended permit tcp any any eq https
access-list inside extended permit udp any any eq domain
access-list inside extended permit tcp any any eq domain
access-list inside extended permit tcp any any eq www
access-list inside extended permit ip any any
access-list inside extended permit icmp any any
access-list dmz extended permit ip any any
access-list dmz extended permit icmp any any
access-list DMZ_IN extended permit icmp any any echo
access-list 101 extended permit icmp any any echo-reply
access-list 101 extended permit icmp any any source-quench
access-list 101 extended permit icmp any any unreachable
access-list 101 extended permit icmp any any time-exceeded
access-list cap extended permit ip 172.16.16.0 255.255.255.0 10.1.4.0 255.255.25
2.0
access-list cap extended permit ip 10.1.4.0 255.255.252.0 172.16.16.0 255.255.25
5.0
pager lines 24
mtu outside 1500
mtu inside 1500
mtu dmz 1500
no failover
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
global (outside) 1 interface
nat (inside) 1 10.1.4.0 255.255.252.0
static (inside,dmz) 10.1.0.0 10.1.16.0 netmask 255.255.252.0
access-group OUT-TO-DMZ in interface outside
access-group inside in interface inside
access-group dmz in interface dmz
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 41.223.156.108 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00
timeout mgcp-pat 0:05:00 sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00
timeout uauth 0:05:00 absolute
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 28800
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 4608000
telnet timeout 5
ssh timeout 5
console timeout 0
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns maximum-length 512
  inspect ftp
  inspect h323 h225
  inspect h323 ras
  inspect netbios
  inspect rsh
  inspect rtsp
  inspect skinny
  inspect esmtp
  inspect sqlnet
  inspect sunrpc
  inspect tftp
  inspect sip
  inspect xdmcp
  inspect icmp
!
service-policy global_policy global
Cryptochecksum:30d296dea4f5ffc1dd4560e075d47076
: end
```

On the other side I should admit to you guys that I'm pretty new to the ASA industry and need to learn a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me to be a routing issue, you don't have a route that sends traffic from the DMZ to your LAN interface nor do you have one that sends traffic from your LAN to your DMZ interface.

Something along the lines of:

```
route inside 172.16.16.0 255.255.255.0 172.16.16.1 1
route dmz 10.1.4.0 255.255.252.0 10.1.4.1 1
```